# mongoTemplate bean could not be found

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a very simple Spring boot app with mvc + mongodb. I used Spring initializer to create the proj with web, thymeleaf and mongo dependencies. I have one controller, one model and a view but I keep on getting an error when trying to execute the app:

```
Description:

Field repo in com.example.CustomerController required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

CustomerController:

```
import model.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by Hello on 25/04/2017.
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerMongoRepo repo;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewingHome(Model model){
        //initDB();
        model.addAttribute("key", "THIS IS FROM THE MODEL");

        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

CustomerMongoRepo:

```
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

        import model.Customer;

public interface CustomerMongoRepo extends CrudRepository {}
```

MainApp:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Customer Model:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

/**
 * Created by Hello on 25/04/2017.
 */

@Document(collection = "customerCollection")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String fName;
    private String sName;

    public Customer(){}

    public Customer(int id, String fName, String sName){
        setfName(fName);
        setsName(sName);
        setId(id);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getsName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public void setsName(String sName) {
        this.sName = sName;
    }


}
```

My Application Properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=customer
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27018/mydb
spring.data.mongo.repositories.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 13):

You are excluding Mongo Configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Then how will spring create mongoTemplate for you. Remove this exclusion or create MongoTemplate manually and register it with application context(using `@Bean`)

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this same problem and my solution was to remove `spring-data-mongodb`:

```xml
<!--<dependency>-->
<!--    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>-->
<!--    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>-->
<!--    <version>3.2.1</version>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
```

and I kept `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is seen that either the two together gave conflict or I need to add 'something' that I did not know.

*Happy code !!! And I hope to be of help to you*

---

#### Update

Later I found something related to what could be described by the problem although I would never finish checking it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389842/7911776

Comment: The worst thing about your answer is that you are right. I was trying to create a bean and that was a mistake. Using the starter package sorted it out.