# How can I force spring boot to use and return the base class in MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I have a base class like (this is an artificial example):

```
@Document(collection = "cars")
public class BaseCar implements Serializable
{
private int number; 
private String color;
...
}
```

Then I have a derived class like:

```
@Document(collection = "cars")
public class FastCar extends BaseCar implements Serializable
{
private int numberOfWonRaces;
... 
}
```

For both I have a MongoRepository class:

```
public interface BaseCarRepository extends MongoRepository<BaseCar, String> {
{ ... }
```

and

```
public interface FastCarRepository extends MongoRepository<FastCar, String> {
{ ... }
```

If I now save a FastCar in MongoDB the I get additionally a _class field added which indicates from where the data is coming from. In this example it shows FastCar.

In my project I have a REST API interface to get cars. I use the findBy function to get a car by its color. For example:

```
BaseCar baseCar = baseCarRep.findByColor(color);
```

Even if I use an object of BaseCar, Springboot is detecting that it is a FastCar and is returning an FastCar object with all the information.

**Question:**
Is there a way to force Springboot to return only a BaseCar? I do not want to send all the information to the REST API interface.

**What I have done so far:**
If I remove the the _class field in the MongoDB, Springboot cannot automatically detect the class anymore and is returning the BaseCar. But I do not want to lose this functionality by forcing Springboot to remove the _class ([Spring data MongoDb: MappingMongoConverter remove _class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810488/spring-data-mongodb-mappingmongoconverter-remove-class/))

It seems that there is also a way with projections to filter the fields which should be returned. This is to me not an elegant way as I have to write down all the fields again and I have to update it as soon as I am updating the BaseCar class.

Thank you for any help.

Philipp