# Mongo db with springdata configurations

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have records with _class attribute in mongodb. Is there any method to ignore this class when retrieve data using spring data.

Comment: According to the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810488/spring-data-mongodb-mappingmongoconverter-remove-class if you pass in an explicit type the `_class` attribute in the record will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can load that using any class, "_class" doesnt impact that