# Remove "_class" from MongoDB - Springboot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and I am trying to connect my SpringBoot App to MongoDB. The GET Request is working completely fine but the POST Request is adding a "_class" field in the data which I don't want. I did some searching and found that I have to add a @Configuration class to solve this issue but when I added the @Configuration class, I am getting the following error :

```
Field mongoDbFactory in com.example.demo.configuration.MongoConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory' that could not be found.
```

My Confuguration class code is as follows :-

MongoConfig.java :-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Autowired
    private MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext;

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() {

        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, 
mongoMappingContext);
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));

        return converter;
    }
}
```

Controller.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;
import com.example.demo.services.TodoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private TodoService todoService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        return todoService.getTodos();
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Todo addTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {
        return  todoService.addTodo(todo);
    }

}
```

TodoService.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;

import java.util.List;

public interface TodoService {

    public List<Todo> getTodos();

    public Todo addTodo(Todo todo);

}
```

TodoServiceImplementation.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;
import com.example.demo.repository.TodoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TodoServiceImplementation implements TodoService{

 @Autowired
 private TodoRepository todoRepository;

 @Override
 public List<Todo> getTodos() {
     return todoRepository.findAll();
 }

 @Override
 public Todo addTodo(Todo todo) {
     return todoRepository.save(todo);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data MongoDb: MappingMongoConverter remove \_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810488/spring-data-mongodb-mappingmongoconverter-remove-class)

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDatabaseFactory factory, MongoMappingContext context,
            BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory);
        MappingMongoConverter mappingConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, context);
        mappingConverter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        return mappingConverter;
    }
}
```

try this