# Jackson Serializer - Java to JSON

Tags: java, jackson

## Context

In one of my team's internal tools, we use the Jackson library to serialize Java objects (Class `A`) to JSON, so that we can eventually store the JSON in MongoDB.

We notice in the JSON file that there are these 2 extra variables `_id` & `_class` for the Java object Class `A`.

The following is the Java definition of Class `A`:

```java
public class A {
  @JsonIgnore
  private int id;
  // ... other variables
}
```

We're trying to find out where the `_class` variable is getting inserted into the JSON file, because this variable is not defined in the Java class. So we suspected it might be the Jackson serializer.

The following is how Class `A` is serialized. Java Class `B` stores a list of Class `A`. Class `B` is the one getting serialized by the Jackson serializer. There is no implementation of a custom serializer for Class `A` or `B`.

Java definition of Class `B`:

```java
public class B {
  List<A> dataList;
  // ... other variables 
}
```

How Class `B` is getting serialized:

```
public class FileWriterService {

  public void writeToFile(B objectB) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fr);

    ...

    bw.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(objectB));
  }
}
```

The sample `JSON` output of Class `A` is as follows:

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "anotherVariableOfClassA": ...,
  "_class": "com.companyName.internalTool.ClassA"
}
```

I don't see anywhere else in the code where Class `A` is getting serialized. The Jackson serializer serializes Class `B` directly.

Is there a way I can remove the `_class` variable in the JSON file?

---

## Reproducing the Code

```java
public class A implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonIgnore
  private int id;
  private String tableName;
  private String sql;

  public A(int id, String tableName, String sql) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.sql = sql;
  }
}
```

```java
public class B {
  private String name;
  private List<A> data;

  public B(String name, List<A> data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

```java
public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initializing A & B
    A a = new A(1, "tableName", "SQL");
    ArrayList<A> list = Arrays.asList(a);
    B b = new B("name", list);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonOutput = mapper.writeValueAsString(b);
    System.out.println(jsonOutput);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it is likely more efficient to use `writeValue(bw, objectB)` (or one of the other `writeValue` methods), than first creating a string with the JSON value, and the writing that string to the writer.

Comment: In any case, please provide an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your prompt response Mark, I appreciate your help, will update the answer shortly

Comment: Which `ArrayList` have you imported for `ArrayList<A> list = Arrays.asList(a);` to compile? Also, the code as shown will produces the error _"java: unreported exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"_, and running the code (after fixing this) results in _"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class nl.lawinegevaar.so.jackson.extrafields.B and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"_

Comment: The `_class` field is not generated by Jackson but by the Mongo serializer. See also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6810488/150978

Comment: @Robert thanks, that's it! you can send an answer with that & i'll accept it